How to solve difficult error when downgrading qiskit version?
I have qiskit 1.2.0 installed currently (and it seems to work perfectly fine).  But I want to use qiskit version 0.29.  When I try pip install qiskit==0.29, it results in a scary cython syntax error.
Following a solution similar to what @mdurant suggested in this question I assumed qiskit version 0.29.0 is only compatible with certain versions of python.  So I then proceeded to downgrade my python version in a new conda environment, by running the following command:
conda create -n "qiskit_029" python=3.8 
I then proceed with pip install qiskit==0.29, which then results in an error.
Without posting the entire traceback, I'll share an excerpt:

  Using cached h5py-3.2.1.tar.gz (368 kB) 

  Installing build dependencies ... done 

  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done 

  Installing backend dependencies ... error 

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 

   

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully. 

  │ exit code: 1 

  ╰─> [212 lines of output] 

      Collecting numpy==1.19.3 

        Using cached numpy-1.19.3.zip (7.3 MB) 

        Installing build dependencies: started 

        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done' 

        Getting requirements to build wheel: started 

        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done' 

        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started 

        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error' 

        error: subprocess-exited-with-error  


...ending with:

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program 

            [end of output]   


I've tried searching around for solutions to this error, but nothing seems fruitful.
What should I try to get around this?  Is there a similar error that might have a similar solution?
Any help/info is appreciated.  Thank you!
Other info:  Using MacOSx Sonoma 14.6.1

What is your operating system ? You seem to still have an "incompatible" OS/python version combination if it tries to compile numpy 1.19.3 from source

Thanks @FlyingTeller.  However, that's odd.  I use Python all the time and never noticed an issue.  Should I have realized that before?

What I meant was, that the combination qiskit=0.29, your OS and python version make an incompatible triplet. Are you using  an x64 or arm64 version of python?

Got it.  While in the virtual environment qiskit_029, I did import platform and platform.architecture which returned ('64bit', '').  So, it's x64.  Thanks for clarifying.

On second thought, some of my failed conda commands say Platform: osx-arm64, so it's arm64.  How do I get around this?

With conda, you can create x64 environments and then run python with Rosetta. See this answer. Create an environment with those commands and then install python3.9 in there. Then try installing again
